# Как передать значение поля класса, а не ссылку на него?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в этих случаях будет присвоено значение, или ссылка?

```
// 1
getRandomArbitrary (DryLand.north.y, DryLand.south.y)
// где getRandomArbitrary - функция, DryLand,DryLand.north и DryLand.south -
// экземпляры классов, а DryLand.north.y и DryLand.south.y - их поля.
// 2
DryLand.outline[DryLand.outline.length - 1].x = DryLand.south.x;
// где DryLand.outline - массив с экземплярами класса (так же можно делать?)
```

И если ссылка, то как присвоить значение?

Comment: Ничего непонятно. "их поля", которые что? Скорее всего - числа. Тогда - значения. Если объекты, тогда ссылки.

Comment: @Igor то есть поле, не являющееся объектом передаст значение, а не ссылку при простом присвоении или передаче в качестве аргумента функции, правильно?

Comment: Примитивные типы передаются по значению, объекты (массив т.ч.) - по ссылке

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ясно, спасибо.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский оформите, как ответ, пожалуйста, я приму.

Comment: Честно говоря мне немного неловко это писать как ответ. Напишу, но...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примитивные типы передаются по значению, объекты (массив т.ч.) - по ссылке

Все типы данных в JavaScript, кроме объектов, являются иммутабельными (значения не могут быть модифицированы, а только перезаписаны новым полным значением).

Это может быть bool, null, числа, undefined, **строки**, Symbol

(https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Объекты же - это значение в памяти, на которое возможно сослаться с помощью идентификатора. При операции, переменная b не копирует содержимое переменной a, а обе эти переменные начинают ссылаться на один и тот же объект.

Массив в *Javascript* - тоже объект. Поэтому он тоже передаётся по ссылке

Comment: нет отдельных int/float

Comment: @Grundy ок......